# Docker swarm LetsEncrypt nginx container writing to /var/log

Tags: docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm running across 4 raspberryPis (1 manager, 3 workers). I was a little surprised today when I was diagnosing a crash on the master node and discovered that the container processes which were running on that host are writing their logs to /var/log on the host machine.

I'd thought that by default (*and my swarm is using the default/basic config from the docker instructions here https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/*), docker writes its logs to a json-log output as part of Docker's own logging structure on the host. Is what I'm seeing expected behaviour, or have I badly misconfigured/misunderstood something?

For example, the letsencrypt image which runs an nginx ingress node for my swarm is writing its logs to /var/log/letsencrypt on my host machine. I wouldn't have thought this possible without me explicitly mounting the /var/log directory in my container spec.

It seems to be writing these certbot debug logs to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log on the host:

```
2020-07-19 07:11:46,615:DEBUG:certbot.main:certbot version: 0.31.0
2020-07-19 07:11:46,616:DEBUG:certbot.main:Arguments: ['-q']
2020-07-19 07:11:46,616:DEBUG:certbot.main:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#standalone,PluginEntryPoint#webroot)
2020-07-19 07:11:46,638:DEBUG:certbot.log:Root logging level set at 30
2020-07-19 07:11:46,639:INFO:certbot.log:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
```

Here's my nginx docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: linuxserver/letsencrypt
    volumes:
      - /share/data/nginx/:/config
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role==manager"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      - PUID=1001
      - PGID=1001
      - URL=mydomain.com
      - SUBDOMAINS=www,mysite1,mysite2
      - VALIDATION=http
      - EMAIL=myemail@myprovider.com
      - TZ=Europe/London
    networks:
      - internal
      - monitoring_front-tier

networks:
  internal:
    external: true
  monitoring_front-tier:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which logging driver is configured on that container:

```
docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.LogConfig.Type}}' <container-id>
```

You can compare the result to how it is supposed to behave, according to the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers

You may also check if you chose to override the default `json-file` logging driver under /etc/docker/daemon.json. If the file does not exist, the json-file driver should be the one in use.

Comment: My nginx container is set to json-file. It looks like my daemon.json only has 2 flags set. One for prometheus metrics, the other for "experimental=true"

Comment: Usually the images send their logs to /dev/stdout. I had a look into the image Dockerfile that you are using. These are the two lines that define where should the logs be sent: https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-letsencrypt./blob/7fc0d59afd8324edfed9412d30dad0b92c28bddb/root/defaults/nginx.conf#L77. Perhaps there's a mount in that path that points at the other end in your /var/log. You can have a look in the container and see

Comment: Alternatively, you can change those two lines with `access_log /dev/stdout;` 
`error_log /dev/stdout;`. The logs should then be fetched by the `json-file` logging driver.

Comment: Good spot, but there's no link from the mounted path to /var/log. I do see the access logs and error logs in that path as expected. Maybe I should post this question directly over on the letsencrypt github page and write back here if I find an answer